# How to create many to many relationships in Entity Framework Core

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-core

I had some research on the internet and found [this blog](https://www.entityframeworktutorial.net/efcore/configure-many-to-many-relationship-in-ef-core.aspx) post on learn Entity Framework, but after I code it, it seemed it wasn't what I wanted.

As well as the example on the blog, I have `Students` and `Courses`. But, I don't want my courses to know whether they are related to courses or not (I wouldn't bother either). But, I want each student to have n courses and that each course could be assigned to more than one student.

```cs
public class Student
{
    public int id {get; set;}
    public string name {get; set;}

    public ICollection<Course> courses {get;set;} //or another proper container abstraction
}

public class Course
{
   public int id {get; set}
   public string name {get; set;}
}
```

So I would query `Student` to know its courses. I implemented this, created a migration, run it on a SQL Server database and implemented a little ASP.NET Core API, with CRUD methods. When I added a second `Student` that used the same  `Course`, the first `Student` loses its `Course`.

Then I implemented the solution the blog suggests:

```
public class StudentCourse
{
    public int student_id {get;set; }
    public Student student {get; set; } 
    public int course_id {get; set; }
    public Course course {get; set; }
}
```

and add to `DbContext` this piece of code:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<StudentCourse>().HasKey(sc => new { sc.SId, sc.CId });

modelBuilder.Entity<StudentCourse>()
    .HasOne<Student>(sc => sc.Student)
    .WithMany(s => s.StudentCourses)
    .HasForeignKey(sc => sc.SId);


modelBuilder.Entity<StudentCourse>()
    .HasOne<Course>(sc => sc.Course)
    .WithMany(s => s.StudentCourses)
    .HasForeignKey(sc => sc.CId);
```

And `Student` and `Course` would each have `ICollection<StudentCourse>` as members. The problem I found with this approach is that I can't create easily an instance of `Student` on my code, because the `Student` itself is a member of its member `StudentCourse`.

Comment: The second approach (separate StudentCourse entity) you have taken is correct. But I am not understanding why it's hard to create a Student though?
Should be,

Student student = new Student
{
    Name = "Some Name"
};

Comment: I guess I need to instanciate and then add the course.

Answer (score 0):

Look in your database.  This

```
public ICollection<Course> courses {get;set;}
```

Will create a *direct* FK relationship on Course referencing Student.  You're not using your StudentCourse entity at all.  Should be

```
public class Student
{
    public int id {get; set;}
    public string name {get; set;}

    public virtual ICollection<StudentCourse> Courses {get;} = new HashSet<StudentCource>();
}
```